# Secondary Angular6 route does nothing on click. No error

Tags: angular, routes, components

The below snippets are part of an angular 6 feature in a larger app.   The top level app has a router outlet, then this feature has 2 of it's own. Clicking the link in comp.html should load the contact component inline, but it does *nothing*.  The expectation is that the html from the ContactComponent gets injected just after the router outlet named popup.  Nope.  No errors either.

You can see the contactcomponent is copy pasta from the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-routes) for this exact issue.  No idea what I'm doing wrong.  I assume something with the routing, but when the route doesn't match I get a 404, which is fine.

**home.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['contact'] }}]">Contact</a>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**routes**

```
const routes: Routes =
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'details/app/:appid',
        component: DetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'history',
        component: HistoryComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactComponent,
        outlet: 'popup',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**ContactComponent.html**

```
<h3>Contact Crisis Center</h3>
<div *ngIf="details">
  {{ details }}
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <label>Message: </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="message" rows="10" cols="35" [disabled]="sending"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<p *ngIf="!sending">
  <button (click)="send()">Send</button>
  <button (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in angular with lazy loaded modules.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24657

In the 2nd link someone suggested a work around.  Using their suggestion I was able to get it to work.  Below is the bare bones setup I created to replicate your issue and apply the work around.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  }
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes =
[
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'history',
        component: HistoryComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactComponent,
        outlet: 'popup',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div><a [routerLink]="['history']">History</a></div>
<div><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['contact'] }}]">Contact</a></div>

<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: wont this generate urls like /home/history /home/contact instead of just /history and /contact as was , I think, the original intent?

Comment: During my tests the urls were as expected, nothing changed with them.

Comment: Sorry, according to you "The below snippets are part of an angular 6 feature in a larger app". So I just setup the App.Module.Routing to be setup how I would expect a larger app to be setup.  You can only have one wildcard redirect at your app module.  So if it's a larger app I would expect you to have a base route like /home/x .. of course home could be the one route you have redirecting the home module so you technically don't need the /home. But the way I setup App.Module as far as I can tell has nothing to do with the problem.  If you want it to be '' instead of 'home' the result should..

Comment: .. be the same.